# Столкнулся с проблемой nginx, сервер не запускается

Tags: nginx

`systemctl status nginx.service`

Пишет следующие:
`nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)`

Не знаю что делать, впервые с таким столкнулся

Comment: У вас запущен другой экземпляр nginx-а или другого веб-сервера который слушает порт 80. Надо его найти и остановить.